# Delete people from Picasa web albums

Tags: picasa-web-albums

Does anyone know if it is possible to delete people from Picasa web albums?

I changed the settings in the desktop application to no longer upload people tags but the people tags still exist in the web albums, they just don't have any photos associated to them. I'd like to delete the people tags but can't figure out how to.

So on the website if I go to 'My Photos' and then click on the 'View all' link next to 'People in my photos' it comes up with a big list of people. However none of them are tagged in any photos. I want to remove people entirely.

Answer (score 2):

> Follow the steps below to delete name tags in Picasa or Picasa Web Albums.
>
> **Picasa**
>
> - **Delete a single name tag**: In the relevant people album, click on
>     the face and click the **Remove**
>     button (or press the delete key).
> - **Delete all name tags for one person**: Right-click (PC) or
>     Control-click (Mac) a people album and
>     select 'Delete Album.'
> - **Delete all name tags in Picasa**: Right-click (PC) or Control-click
>     (Mac) on each people album and select
>     'Delete Album.'
>
> **Picasa Web Albums**
>
> - **Delete a single name tag**: When viewing an individual photo, click the
>     'x' icon in the upper right corner of
>     the name box around the face.

From the horse's mouth: http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=161808

Comment: Thanks Alex but the step for Picasa Web Albumns deletes the tag from the photo but doesn't delete the person. You can still see the person if you go to MyPhotos then click on the 'People In My Photos View All' link. I'll update the question to try and explain this better.

Comment: There is no + sign to click on and delete. I think it is impossible to delete people tag without deleting the photo itself.